# how to run the executable from localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, localhost, exe

I tried to run exe file with-out from localhost ;

Like :

```
 string installerFilePath; installerFilePath = @"D:\MYInstaller.exe";
            System.Diagnostics.Process installerProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            installerProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(installerFilePath, "/q");
```

Here installtion is runnning with out silen mode.

using below code  : it is lanchin exe file with out running exe file

```
string installerFilePath; installerFilePath ="http://localhost/BusinessAccounting/ReportViewer/MY.exe";


                System.Diagnostics.Process installerProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                installerProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(installerFilePath, "/q");
```

can one expalin with out lanching how can i run the exe file ...

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create a `ProcessStartInfo` class instance and set up its property `WindowStyle` to `minimized` or `hidden` to hide console window if that is what you want.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(<exename>, <args>);
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.WorkingDirectory = fi.DirectoryName;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
```